# Why Does the d3-voronoi-treemap Build Fail in Vite?

Tags: svelte, vite, esbuild

I recently tried to upgrade a Svelte project from using Rollup to Vite, matching the settings on a fresh Svelte project. My project includes a D3 Voronoi Treemap, using the plugin [d3-voronoi-treemap](https://github.com/Kcnarf/d3-voronoi-treemap).

The build fails on d3-voronoi-treemap consistently, with an error I find confusing:

```
npm run dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> voronoi-treemap-test@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v3.0.4  ready in 1001 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

X [ERROR] No matching export in "node_modules/d3-voronoi-map/index.js" for import "default"

    node_modules/d3-voronoi-treemap/src/d3-voronoi-treemap.js:1:7:
      1 │ import voronoiMap from 'd3-voronoi-map';
        ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1624
  let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
              ^

Error: Build failed with 1 error:
node_modules/d3-voronoi-treemap/src/d3-voronoi-treemap.js:1:7: ERROR: No matching export in "node_modules/d3-voronoi-map/index.js" for import "default"
    at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1624:15)
    at C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1266:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1046:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1264:7)
    at C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1377:14
    at C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:678:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:775:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Workzone\voronoi-treemap-test\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:644:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 7,
        file: 'node_modules/d3-voronoi-treemap/src/d3-voronoi-treemap.js',
        length: 10,
        line: 1,
        lineText: "import voronoiMap from 'd3-voronoi-map';",
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'No matching export in "node_modules/d3-voronoi-map/index.js" for import "default"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

This is from a fresh Svelte project created with `npm create vite@latest my-app -- --template svelte`, but the error is no different from my project.

What I don't understand is the error statement: `No matching export in "node_modules/d3-voronoi-map/index.js" for import "default"`. The [d3-voronoi-treemap plugin is in UMD format](https://github.com/Kcnarf/d3-voronoi-treemap/blob/master/rollup.config.js), and it should be [converted into ESM](https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html#the-why). The error suggests that Vite is looking for a default export as if it were expecting ESM, and UMD being a different module format it fails.

I'm really struggling to pin down where the error could be. Is Vite not correctly converting d3-voronoi-treemap to ESM when building? Is there something fundamentally wrong with d3-voronoi-treemap? Or is it esbuild not handling some dependency of d3-voronoi-treemap correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://github.com/Kcnarf/d3-voronoi-map#installing) shows that it should be imported like this:

```js
import { voronoiMapSimulation } from 'd3-voronoi-map';
```

The `package.json` has a `jsnext:main` so the UMD version of the package is not used:

```json
  "main": "build/d3-voronoi-map.js",
  "jsnext:main": "index",
```

You can see from the error that it imports `node_modules/d3-voronoi-map/index.js`, which looks like this:

```js
export { voronoiMapSimulation } from './src/d3-voronoi-map';
export { default as voronoiMapInitialPositionRandom } from './src/initial-position-policies/random';
export { default as voronoiMapInitialPositionPie } from './src/initial-position-policies/pie';
export { default as d3VoronoiMapError } from './src/d3-voronoi-map-error';
```

Comment: So, the issue is specifically that d3-voronoi-treemap imports d3-voronoi-map [like so](https://github.com/Kcnarf/d3-voronoi-treemap/blob/master/src/d3-voronoi-treemap.js#L1):

`import voronoiMap from 'd3-voronoi-map';`

But it should be:

`import { voronoiMapSimulation } from 'd3-voronoi-map';`

Bit strange considering it's the same author!

Comment: @pcclarke: True. Just checked whether someone else noticed the issue; [apparently so](https://github.com/Kcnarf/d3-voronoi-treemap/issues/18).